# Are there other ways to describe formal languages other than grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I'm looking for mathematical theories that deal with describing formal languages (set of strings) in general and not just grammar hierarchies.

Comment: Note that there are many, many grammer types beyond the classic Chomsky ones, for instance *multiple*, *coupled* and *length dependent* context-free grammars, respectively (easily googlable).

Comment: Found some related [Wikipedia table with more structure and links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Formal_languages_and_grammars)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are plenty of possibilities. Others have already mentioned automata which offer a rich selection. Consider the following frameworks, too:

1. Some languages can be defined directly by *(co)[inductive definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_definition)*. For instance, the smallest fixpoint of
   $\qquad \begin{align*}
     \phantom{a} \\
     &\phantom{\Rightarrow}\ \varepsilon \in L \\
     w \in L &\Rightarrow aw \in L \\
     aw \in L &\Rightarrow baw \in L \\
     \phantom{a}
   \end{align*}$
   is the same language as the one described by $(ba\mid a)^*$, the largest fixpoint is $(ba\mid a)^\omega$. Note that such a definition can also be written in calculus or [inference rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) form:
   $ \qquad \begin{align*} \phantom{a}\\
     \frac{}{\varepsilon}, \quad \frac{w}{aw}, \quad \frac{aw}{baw} \\
     \phantom{a}
   \end{align*}$
2. Words define *word structures* that can be used as models of *logical formula*. Essentially, every word defines the domain of its positions $D_w = \{1, \dots, n\}$, predicates $P_a : D \to \{0,1\}$ so that $P_a(i) \Longleftrightarrow w_i = a$ for all $a \in \Sigma$, a predicate $<$ that is $<$ from $\mathbb{N}$ restricted to $D_w$ and a predicate $\operatorname{suc} : D_w \times D_w \to \{0,1\}$ that is true if and only if the second parameter is the direct successor of the fist.
   So for instance, if $w = aababaab$ then
   $ \qquad \begin{align*} \phantom{a}\\
     S_w \models \forall\, i. \forall\, j.\ (P_b(i)\ \land\ \operatorname{suc}(i,j)) \to \lnot P_b(j); \\
     \phantom{a}
   \end{align*}$
   in fact, this [first-order formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) defines---via the set of all word structures that fulfill it---the same language as $(ba\mid a)^*$. The corresponding $\omega$-language $(ba\mid a)^\omega$ is described by the [LTL formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic)
   $ \qquad \begin{align*} \phantom{a}\\
     \square\,(P_b \to\bigcirc(\lnot P_b)) \\
     \phantom{a}
   \end{align*}$
   Several equivalences between classic language classes and certain logics are known. For example, [FO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) corresponds to star-free languages, weak [MSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic) to regular languages and [MSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic) to $\omega$-regular languages. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10799/98) for references.
3. Something orthogonal to classic classes are *pattern languages*. Assume a terminal alphabet $\Sigma$ and a variable alphabet $X=\{x_1, x_2,\dots\}$. A string $p \in (\Sigma \cup X)^+$ is called a *pattern*. Let $\mathcal{H}= \{\sigma \mid \sigma : X \to \Sigma^*\}$ the set of substitutions. We define the language of a pattern $p$ as
   $ \qquad \begin{align*} \phantom{a}\\
     \mathcal{L}(p) = \{\sigma(p) \mid \sigma \in \mathcal{H}\}. \\
     \phantom{a}
   \end{align*}$
   Note that $\sigma$ is extended to work on patterns; terminal symbols are left unchanged.
   As an example, consider $\mathcal{L}(x_1abbax_1)= \{wabbaw\mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$.
   Note that we allow substitutions to delete variables; some properties of the class of pattern languages are hugely different for deleting vs. non-deleting substitutions. Pattern languages are of particular interest in [Gold-style learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification_in_the_limit).

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at [automata theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory). There's plenty of material about it.

In example, you may define a regular language with a [nondeterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) with labelled edges: a string belongs to the language if the automaton can follow the transitions labelled by its characters and stops in a final state.

Also, a context-free grammar may be recognized by a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

Another way to define languages is by means of [Turing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).

Answer (score 5):

Further to the other answers, one can describe and classify languages in terms of "generators" and closure properties. For example, it makes sense to talk about the smallest [AFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages) generated by some language. A good place to start learning about this type of description is [this](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreTransductions/LivreTransductions.html) book, although it can be quite hard to find a hard copy of it.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) there are four types of formal languages(each of them is a subset of the ones after it):

A **regular formal language** can be described by:

1. Regular Grammar
2. Finite Automaton (Deterministic/Nondeterministic)
3. Regular Expression

1., 2. and 3. are equivalent and from one of them you can construct the others.

A **context-free formal language** can be described by:

1. Context-free Grammar
2. Pushdown automaton

Also 1. and 2. are equivalent.

A **context-sensitive formal language** can be described by:

1. Linear bounded automaton (Turing machine with restricted tape)

A **recursively enumerable formal language** can be described by:

1. Total Turing machine

Comment: And all the other language classes?

Comment: And the classless languages?

Comment: Chomsky doesn't say these are the *only* types of languages - they are just four types he finds important, and we still find them important, but there are many other types.