# Star free language vs. regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata

I was wondering, since $a^*$ is itself a star-free language, is there a regular language that is not a star-free language? Could you give an example?

---

*(from [wikipdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language#cite_ref-Law235_1-0))* Lawson defines star-free languages as:

> A regular language is said to be star-free if it can be described by a regular expression constructed from the letters of the alphabet, the empty set symbol, all boolean operators – including complementation – and concatenation but no Kleene star.

---

Here is the proof of $a^*$ being star-free:

> $\emptyset$ is star-free $\Longrightarrow$
>   $\Sigma^*=\bar{\emptyset}$ is star-free $\Longrightarrow$
>   If $A\subseteq\Sigma$ then $\Sigma^*A\Sigma^*$ is star-free $\Longrightarrow$
>   If $A\subseteq\Sigma$ then $A^*=\overline{\Sigma^*(\Sigma \setminus A)\Sigma^*}$ is star-free

In the last line we have $A^*=\overline{\Sigma^*(\Sigma \setminus A)\Sigma^*}$, because any word that is not of form $A^*$ contains a letter in $\Sigma \setminus A$ and vice versa.

Comment: @reinierpost You are misreading the equation. There are two complement bars on top of $A$ and on top of the whole equation. Sorry, I guess I was not good at formatting in 2013.

Comment: @reinierpost I edited the post to make it easier to read. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regular languages are those that can be described by *weak monadic second order logic* (WMSO) [1].

Star-free languages are those that can be described by *first order logic with $<$* (FO[<]) [2].

The two logics are not equally powerful. One example for a language that is WMSO-definable but not FO[<]-definable is $(aa)^*$ (which is clearly regular³); this can be shown using *[Ehrenfeucht-Fraissé games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game)*⁴.

---

1. [Weak Second-Order Arithmetic and Finite Automata](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19600060105) by Büchi (1960)
2. *Counter-free automata* by McNaughton and Papert (1971)
3. A WMSO-formula for $(aa)^*$ is

   $\ \begin{align}
           \bigl[ \forall x. P_a(x)\bigr] \land \Bigl[ \exists x. P_a(x) \to \bigl[ \exists X. X(0) 
                 &\land [\forall x,y. X(x) \land \operatorname{suc}(x,y) \to \lnot X(y)] \\
                 &\land [\forall x,y. \lnot X(x) \land \operatorname{suc}(x,y) \to X(y)] \\
                 &\land [\forall x. \operatorname{last}(x) \to \lnot X(x)] \bigr] \Bigr] \;.
       \end{align}$

   (If the word is not empty, $X$ is the set of all even indices.)
4. See also [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Raluca/index.html).

Comment: I know what is "monadic" in the logic. Do you happen to know what is the "weak" restriction?

Comment: @HendrikJan: It's just that both model and sets have to be finite; MSO deals with infinite words (it corresponds to $\omega$-regular languages, to be precise).

Answer (score 15):

Schützenberger (1965) gave an algebraic characterization of the star-free languages: a regular language is star-free if and only if its syntactic monoid is aperiodic. Contrary to the logical characterization (star-free = FO[<]), this algebraic characterization gives an **algorithm** to decide whether a given regular language is star-free (the regular language can be given by a finite automaton, a regular expression or a regular grammar). Using the logical characterization (due to McNaughton and Papert) one can then decide the following problem: given a WMSO formula, is there a FO formula describing the same language?

M.-P. Schützenberger, On finite monoids having only trivial subgroups, *Information and Control* **8** (1965), 190-194.

R.~McNaughton and S.~Papert, Counter-free automata, The M.I.T. Press, Cambridge, Mass.-London, 1971.

A full proof of Schützenberger's theorem can be found in various textbooks or survey papers. For an elementary presentation of the corresponding algorithm (without a proof), see

J.-É. Pin, Finite semigroups and recognizable languages : an introduction, in *NATO Advanced Study Institute Semigroups, Formal Languages and Groups*, J. Fountain (éd.), 1-32, Kluwer academic publishers, (1995).

Answer (score 8):

Star free languages are described by regular expressions that include concatenation, complementation, union, intersection, but no Kleene-star.

Since regular languages are closed under all these operations (where complementation is the crucial point), then every star-free language is also regular.

Perhaps you mean the converse? Are all regular languages star-free?
The answer to the latter is no. See [this paper](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/DG-WT08.pdf) for details.

Comment: yes I meant the converse, edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

A simple separating example is (aa)*. More sophisticated: All binary strings with even (or odd) parity.

Comment: What does this add over the accepted answer?

Comment: @Raphael The parity example. Though it would be nice if Holger explained why it's not star-free.